# Share audio file from the res/raw folder thorugh Share Intent in Android

Tags: android, audio, share-intent

I'm trying to share an audio file from my res/raw folder. What I've done so far is:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sound); //parse path to uri
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); //share intent
share.setType("audio/*");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share sound to"));
```

When I choose to share it on GMail, for example, it says something like "Failed to attach empty file". Looks like I'm not getting the right file path, so I'm basically sharing nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Copy the audio file from the resource to external storage and then share it:

```
InputStream inputStream;
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
try {
    inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sound);
    fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
            new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "sound.mp3"));

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    inputStream.close();
    fileOutputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
        Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/sound.mp3" ));
intent.setType("audio/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share sound"));
```

Add `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to *AndroidManifest.xml* file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

> What am I doing wrong?

Few apps handle `android.resource` `Uri` values correctly. Your choices are:

1. Drop the feature, or
2. Copy the data from the resource into a file, then use `FileProvider`, perhaps in conjunction with [my `LegacyCompatCursorWrapper`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider#usage-legacycompatcursorwrapper), or
3. Use [my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider), which can serve `raw` resources directly, or
4. Copy the data from the resource into a file, then use `Uri.fromFile()`, but this looks like it will stop working with the next version of Android, based on preliminary results from testing with the N Developer Preview

Comment: Does FileProvider work with internal files like the ones under the res/raw folder? If so, could you please give me some code example on how to do it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MiquelPerez: "Does FileProvider work with internal files like the ones under the res/raw folder?" -- those are resources. They are files on your development machine. They are not files on the device. `StreamProvider` can stream resources directly; there is a sample app in the project repo that shows how to use it (albeit using `assets/` rather than raw resources).

Comment: Please see my recent answer to tue question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: It was causing a NullPointException. This is what was I doing:

```
File dest = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sound);

try
{
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(dest, "sound.mp3"));
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ( (len = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1){
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();

}catch (Exception e) {}


 final Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Soundboard.this, "myapp.folagor.miquel.folagor", dest); //NullPointerException right here!!

 final Intent intent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(Soundboard.this)
                        .setType("audio/*")
                        .setSubject(getString(R.string.share_subject))
                        .setStream(uri)
                        .setChooserTitle(R.string.share_title)
                        .createChooserIntent()
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET)
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

  startActivity(intent);
```

The code was just fine. The only problem was that on the Manifest's permisions, I had "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" instead of "android.permissions.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE". So I was not having permision to write in the external storage, which caused a FileNotFoundException due to the lack of permision. Now it works fine!